# Windows phone 7 api изменение настроек энергосбережения

Tags: windows-phone-7, энергосбережение

Пишу утилиту под windows phone 7. Необходима функция для изменения состояния энергосбережения. Есть ли api для реализации такой возможности?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ с форму разработчиков майкрософта:

> Соответствующего API для управления настройками энергосбережения нет. Есть только API для проверки состояния электропитания. Таким образом написать приложение (для публикации в Marketplace) для управления настройками энергосбережения на данный момент невозможно.